# Cannot Push To Origin In Github Desktop Interface (Windows)

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I cannot **push to origin** using Github Desktop. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

I have already setup the personal access token.

[image]

I try to sign out and then sign in again from github desktop app.

[image]

But still got error :

```
Authentication failed. Some common reasons include:

- You are not logged in to your account: see File > Options.
- You may need to log out and log back in to refresh your token.
- You do not have permission to access this repository.
- The repository is archived on GitHub. Check the repository settings to confirm you are still permitted to push commits.
- If you use SSH authentication, check that your key is added to the ssh-agent and associated with your account.
- If you use SSH authentication, ensure the host key verification passes for your repository hosting service.
- If you used username / password authentication, you might need to use a Personal Access Token instead of your account password. Check the documentation of your repository hosting service.
```

For note :

I have reset my PC and then install back the github desktop app then clone the repository.

Then I cannot push to origin. What could cause the issue and how to solve this?

This is github desktop app. I didn't use git bash. But I have installed the git bash too.